# c#/vb.net combining image with transparent border

Tags: .net, graphics

I want combine 2 images,here an example.

I have the image of the truck and the image of the pensil, I want combine them as show in the bottom row, created with  gimp using selection from alpha, expand, and clear.

[image]

Actually the code is minimal:

```
Dim base = Image.FromFile("small_truck.png")
Dim add As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("pencil.png")
Dim frame As New Bitmap(base.Width, base.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(frame)
g.DrawImage(base, 0, 0)
g.DrawImage(add, base.Width - add.Width, base.Height - add.Height, add.Width, add.Height)
frame.Save("output.png")
```

does someone know how to replicate gimp workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

```
Dim base = Image.FromFile("small_truck.png")
Dim add As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("pencil.png")
Dim frame As New Bitmap(base.Width, base.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(frame)
g.DrawImage(base, 0, 0)
g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy
Dim startx = base.Width - add.Width, starty = base.Height - add.Height
For y = 0 To add.Height - 1
    For x = 0 To add.Width - 1
        Dim c = add.GetPixel(x, y)
        If c.A >= 128 Then
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, startx + x - 1, starty + y - 1, 3, 3)
        End If
    Next
Next
g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver
g.DrawImage(add, startx, starty, add.Width, add.Height)
frame.Save("output_32.png")
```

I keep here question and answer, maybe it will be useful for someone.

Comment: Well done! Worth looking at the `Using` statement to properly dispose of `IDisposable` objects (Image, Bitmap & Graphics in your example) considering how much memory can be eaten when playing with images: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects